# Do AVR can do anything ARM can't?

Tags: avr, arm

Do AVR (mega, xmega, AVR32) has any capability that ARM based MCUs don't have?
or can achieve particular purpose cheaper or easier?

Simply, do AVR worth learning?

Comment: Does "be simple" count?

Comment: There are fewer and fewer reasons.  The ATmegas will run at 5v unlike most ARM parts... they also come in DIP packages if you still care (though there's one ARM device that does).  Or maybe you want to play with Arduino code unmodified.  AVR32 is a completely different architecture.

Answer (score 3):

IMPORTANT POINT: When comparing MCUs, compare a specific model to another specific model, not an MCU family to another MCU family. Make your choosing similar, For example you can compare an ARM Cortex M4 MCU to an AVR32 MCU since they are both 32-bit-architecture based. Then you can choose a specific model from each one to compare.

Another point, You are comparing a family of MCU to a vendor-neutral architecture. Choose a vendor that manufactures ARM-Based MCUs to compare it with AVR, because ARM is an architecture, each vendor takes the architecture and adds its own features and system.

After that you can decide between ARM and AVR.

And as an answer to your question, I think yes, It worth learning. AVR is one of the popular architecture. And It won't harm to learn AVR and ARM :)

Answer (score 2):

There are advantages to learning one of the simpler platforms like AVR (or PIC) even if there are platforms that can do all that they can do, plus more.

The biggest one is how easy it is to learn one of the simple platforms.  Starting with microprocessors is a matter of learning CONCEPTS, not procedures.  If you pick one of the simple platforms, you'll have more tools available for you to use, more books, blogs, tutorials, and examples to draw from, and you'll have a bigger user group available for you to ask for help when all else fails.

Once you have these concepts down, it is much easier to move on to the big boys.

So, yes, until you know what you're doing, you will have an easier time developing on an AVR